# UFT 14.03 not generating scripts after attempting to test the windows calculator application

Tags: automated-tests, hp-uft

UFT 14.03 is not generating any scripts after attempting to test the windows calculator application. How can I fix this?

Comment: Hi, I am reviewing your post. You might want to add some code. It makes it easier for the SO community to reproduce your query.
Please check here on how to ask good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

In the [Record and Run settings](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uft/en/14.03/UFT_Help/Content/Addins_Guide/Record_Settings_Standard_Tab.htm) make sure you've either selected **Record and run test on any open Windows-based application** or specified the calculator program for the **Record and run only on**.